# Excel: create columns based on one column values AND another column categories

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 columns in an Excel "table", one called "gender" and the other "height".

I would like to create two independent columns:
One that would populate only the height value if the gender cell of the rows contain "female". And one only for men heights.

For instance, let's say I have:

```
Gender cell row1 = female
Gender cell row2 = male
Gender cell row3 = female
Gender cell row3 = male


Height cell row 1 = 1.7
Height cell row 1 = 1.6
Height cell row 1 = 1.5
Height cell row 1 = 1.9
```

So I would like my custom column "female heights" to be created as such:

```
female heights cell row 1 = 1.7
female heights cell row 2 = 1.5
```

And I would like my custom column "male heights" to be created as such:

```
male heights cell row 1 = 1.6
male heights cell row 2 = 1.9
```

I know how to count how many females (or male) are in the Gender column =>

```
COUNTIF(D:D,"female)
COUNTIF(D:D,"male)
```

But I don't know how to create a new columns taking values of the Height column only if the Gender column value is one or the other. It's a big leap from the COUNTIF function.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does your version of Excel support the `FILTER` function?

Comment: I have Excel 2016 on mac and I need to mention (I forgot) that my columns are part of an Excel "table", not just a list of data. So each column can be filter via its header. However, I need to create two histograms (male/female) based on the frequency distribution. So I think I need to create two columns of heights, one for males and one for females, first and make histograms based on those two newly created columns. I can't just filter for one to create a histogram otherwise I won't have the data available for the other at the same time. I hope I'm clear. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I edited my question and its content to be more accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Excel 365 for Mac, then you can use FILTER like this:

```
=FILTER($B$2:$B$25,$A$2:$A$25=D1)
```

Where D1 = "female".  It will spill the results as shown in columns D and E. You can pick that up with a FREQUENCY function as shown in columns H & I with a set of BINs that I put in place for illustration.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution from reading your comments: copy and paste the range into new columns, sort by gender, and remove all the males. Then copy and paste the range into a new column again and sort by gender, and this time remove all the females.

This will make it easy to generate a histogram.

Comment: This is the obvious way and your answer is perfectly valid. I was just wondering if, without Visual Basic, there was a way to dynamically create columns of undefined number of rows based on some condition. But I suppose there isn't.